# checkboxinput server issues in R

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny, shinydashboard

I want to have a checkbox in my UI that will act as an if statement in my server but I'm not sure how to properly code the part in the server. In this example, I would like the graph to output when the box is checked.

Here is my code

```
ui <- fluidPage(

    titlePanel("title"),

    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            checkboxInput("EF", "Efficient Frontier")
        ),

        mainPanel(
            fluidRow(
                align = "center",
                plotOutput("Graphw")
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
                if(input$EF){
                    X <- function(a,b,c){
                        plot(c(a,b),c(b,c))
                         }
                }
    
                OPw <- reactiveValues()
                OPw$PC <- X(5,10,15)
                
                output$Graphw <- renderPlot({ 
                    OPw$PC
                })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I need to add some kind of reactive values but Im not sure where. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `plot` function doesn't return anything. There is no need to use a reactive.  `ggplot` for example, does return a plot to store in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this without using `reactiveValues`. Make the function `X` as independent function which can be called under `renderPlot`.

```
library(shiny)

X <- function(a,b,c){
  plot(c(a,b),c(b,c))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("title"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("EF", "Efficient Frontier")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        align = "center",
        plotOutput("Graphw")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$Graphw <- renderPlot({ 
    if(input$EF){
      X(5,10,15)
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful. I had a follow up question which I posted here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70810287/r-shiny-checkboxes-and-action-button-combination-issue) . Feel free to give it a look if you have time :)

Answer (score 1):

If the efficient frontier takes some time to plot, we can use `conditionalPanel` to show or hide the `plotOutput` instead of re-rendering each time the `checkboxInput` is pressed.

```
library(shiny)

X <- function(a, b, c) {
  plot(c(a, b), c(b, c))
}

library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("EF", "Efficient Frontier")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        align = "center",
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.EF == true",
          plotOutput("Graphw")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$Graphw <- renderPlot({
    X(5, 10, 5)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Another version that uses `reactiveValues` with `ggplot`

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("EF", "Efficient Frontier")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        align = "center",
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "input.EF == true",
          plotOutput("Graphw")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  X <- function(a, b, c) {
    ggplot(mapping = aes(x = c(a, b), y = c(b, c))) +
      geom_point()
  }

  OPw <- reactiveValues(PC = NULL)

  observe({
    OPw$PC <- X(5, 10, 5)
  })



  output$Graphw <- renderPlot({
    OPw$PC
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```