# R shiny - checkboxes and action button combination issue

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny, shinydashboard

I have 2 checkboxes and 1 action button. When clicking on either of the checkboxes, a graph should output BUT only after clicking on the action button. The code I have bellow does this well already. My issue here is that once the action button has been clicked and the graph generated, unclicking the checkbox removes the graph. Similarly, clicking again generates a new graph without clicking on the action button. I would like for the graph to stay on the screen for as long as I dont click on the action button again. I imagine this has to do with "isolating" the checkboxes but Im not too sure how to do so.

As a side note, imagine there was a third function generating a plot in my server when clicking on the action button (regardless of the checkboxes). Is there a way to code my "showmodal, removemodal" such that the pop up stays while all functions are running (instead of only during the first function)?

Here is my code

```
library(shiny)

#Function 1
X <- function(a,b,c){
    plot(c(a,b),c(b,c))
}

#Function 2
Y <- function(d,e,f){
    plot(c(d,e),c(e,f))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    
    titlePanel("title"),
    
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            checkboxInput("EF", "Efficient Frontier"),
            checkboxInput("MonteCarlo", "Monte Carlo Simulation"),
            actionButton("Go", "Go", style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4; margin: auto")
        ),
        
        mainPanel(
            fluidRow(
                align = "center",
                conditionalPanel(condition = "input.EF == true", plotOutput("GraphEF")),
                conditionalPanel(condition = "input.MonteCarlo == true", plotOutput("GraphMC"))
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    OPw <- reactiveValues()
    output$Graphw <- renderPlot({ 
        OPw$PC}, height = 400, width = 400)
    
    observeEvent(input$Go, {
        showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer=NULL)) 
    
        output$GraphEF <- renderPlot({ #Efficient Frontier
            if(input$EF){
                X(5,10,15)
            }
        }, height = 550, width = 700)
        
        output$GraphMC <- renderPlot({ #Monte Carlo Simulation
            if(input$MonteCarlo){
                Y(5,10,15)
            }
        },height = 550, width = 700)
        
        removeModal() #Removes Loading Pop-up Message
        
        
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Don’t nest your reactives.

Comment: Not sure I get your point

Comment: @Limey wanted to tell you, that you should never call `renderPlot` (or any other render*-function) inside an `observeEvent` or `observe` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should use `eventReactive()`.  Try this

```
library(shiny)

# Function 1
X <- function(a, b, c) {
  plot(c(a, b), c(b, c))
}

# Function 2
Y <- function(d, e, f) {
  plot(c(d, e), c(e, f))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("EF", "Efficient Frontier"),
      checkboxInput("MonteCarlo", "Monte Carlo Simulation"),
      actionButton("Go", "Go", style = "color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4; margin: auto")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        align = "center", 
        uiOutput("plot1"),
        plotOutput("GraphMC")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  GEF <- eventReactive(input$Go, {
    if (input$EF) {
      X(5, 10, 15)
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })
  
  showme <- eventReactive(input$Go, {
    if (input$EF) TRUE else FALSE
  })

  GMC <- eventReactive(input$Go, {
    if (isolate(input$MonteCarlo)) {
      Y(5, 10, 15)
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })
  
  output$GraphMC <- renderPlot({
    GMC()
  })
  
  output$GraphEF <- renderPlot({ # Efficient Frontier
    GEF()
  })
  
  output$plot1 <- renderUI({
    if (showme()) {plotOutput("GraphEF")} else NULL
  })

  observeEvent(input$Go, {
    showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer = NULL))

    Sys.sleep(2)
    
    removeModal() # Removes Loading Pop-up Message
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The issue with this is that by removing the conditional panels, the “second” graph now outputs bellow the “empty” first graph if the second checkbox is marked but the first isnt

Comment: Try the updated code.

Comment: it works thanks a lot! Also, I made a new post with an MRE as you suggested if you want to check it out :) <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70828547/r-shiny-conditional-panel-output-shifted>

Comment: I couldnt actually reproduce your solution since my code is more complex than this example I gave. I made a new post if you wanna check it out <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841734/r-shiny-checkbox-issue>

Answer (score 2):

Leaving a `conditionalPanel`-approach, which is referring to a discussion [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70828702/9841389):

```
library(shiny)

# Function 1
X <- function(a, b, c) {
  plot(c(a, b), c(b, c))
}

# Function 2
Y <- function(d, e, f) {
  plot(c(d, e), c(e, f))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("EF", "Efficient Frontier"),
      checkboxInput("MonteCarlo", "Monte Carlo Simulation"),
      actionButton("Go", "Go", style = "color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4; margin: auto")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        align = "center", 
        conditionalPanel("output.showme == true", plotOutput("GraphEF")),
        plotOutput("GraphMC")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  GEF <- eventReactive(input$Go, {
    if (input$EF) {
      X(5, 10, 15)
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })
  
  output$showme <- eventReactive(input$Go, {
    if (input$EF) TRUE else FALSE
  })
  outputOptions(output, "showme", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
  
  GMC <- eventReactive(input$Go, {
    if (isolate(input$MonteCarlo)) {
      Y(5, 10, 15)
    } else {
      NULL
    }
  })
  
  output$GraphMC <- renderPlot({
    GMC()
  })
  
  output$GraphEF <- renderPlot({ # Efficient Frontier
    GEF()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Go, {
    showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer = NULL))
    
    Sys.sleep(2)
    
    removeModal() # Removes Loading Pop-up Message
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Furthermore, please see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895710/passing-reactive-values-to-conditionalpanel-condition).

Comment: this works well but unfortunately my code is a bit more complex so I couldnt reproduce your solution. I made a new post here if you wanna check it out <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70841734/r-shiny-checkbox-issue>

Answer (score 0):

The modal is working well, because both functions take so little time to run it creates de sensation than is there less than it should be. We can show this by adding a `sys.sleep` to simulate a long calculation.

Regarding the checkboxes, using `conditionalPanel` will hide or show the plots independently of the presence of `isolate` inside the server. A workaround is just to return `NULL` when the checkbox is not clicked.

```
library(shiny)

# Function 1
X <- function(a, b, c) {
  plot(c(a, b), c(b, c))
}

# Function 2
Y <- function(d, e, f) {
  plot(c(d, e), c(e, f))
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("title"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("EF", "Efficient Frontier"),
      checkboxInput("MonteCarlo", "Monte Carlo Simulation"),
      actionButton("Go", "Go", style = "color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4; margin: auto")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        align = "center",
        plotOutput("GraphEF"),
        plotOutput("GraphMC")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  OPw <- reactiveValues()
  output$Graphw <- renderPlot(
    {
      OPw$PC
    },
    height = 400,
    width = 400
  )

  observeEvent(input$Go, {
    showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer = NULL))

    output$GraphEF <- renderPlot(
      { # Efficient Frontier
        if (isolate(input$EF)) {
          X(5, 10, 15)
        } else {
          NULL
        }
      },
      height = 550,
      width = 700
    )
    Sys.sleep(2)
    output$GraphMC <- renderPlot(
      { # Monte Carlo Simulation
        if (isolate(input$MonteCarlo)) {
          Y(5, 10, 15)
        } else {
          NULL
        }
      },
      height = 550,
      width = 700
    )

    removeModal() # Removes Loading Pop-up Message
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hey I just tried your solution but it seems like it doesnt really changes anything? the graphs are still disappearing as soon as I uncheck the boxes