# R shiny - Checkbox and conditional panels issues

Tags: r, checkbox, shiny

I have 2 separate issues here. First, the conditional panels for my data frame output are not working properly. Regardless of which checkbox you click on, I would like the data frame to output at the same location all the time. Currently, only the "efficient frontier" checkbox outputs at the right location. The "Monte Carlo" checkbox and the combination of both checkboxes shifts the data frame to the right for some reason..

The second issue I have has to do with "isolating" my checkboxes. Currently, if you change the checkboxes after outputting the results using the "Go" button, the graph will come and go. I would like for the graph output to only be modified when you click on the "Go" button.

Here is a snippet of my code. Everything after line 165 is just functions so don't waste any time looking at that.

Thank you for your help! :D

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)                            
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(zoo)
library(xts)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(RiskPortfolios)
library(quadprog)
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Analysis",
                         
     tabPanel(
         "Performance",
         
         titlePanel("Performance"),
         br(),
         
         sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
             ),
             mainPanel(
             )
         )),
     
     tabPanel(
         "Construction",
         
         titlePanel("Construction"),
         br(),
         
         sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
                 textInput("Stockw","Ticker (Yahoo)"),
                 numericInput("Sharesw","Number of Shares",0, min = 0, step = 1),
                 selectInput("Countryw","Country",choices = c("Canada","United States")),
                 
                 column(12,
                        splitLayout(cellWidths = c("70%", "30%"),
                                    actionButton("actionw", "Add",icon("dollar-sign"),  
                                                 style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
                                    actionButton("resetw", "Reset",icon("trash"),  
                                                 style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"))),
                 
                 br(),
                 br(),
                 checkboxInput("EF", "Efficient Frontier"),
                 checkboxInput("MonteCarlo", "Monte Carlo Simulation"),
                 
                 fluidRow(
                     align = "center",
                     p("____________________________________"),
                     p("Ready to launch?", style = "font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold"),
                     actionButton("Gow", "Go!", style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4; margin: auto")),
                 
             ),
             
             mainPanel(
                 column(12,
                        tableOutput("tablew"), 
                        style = "height:185px; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; border-radius: 8px; background-color: #f7f7f7;text-align: left; overflow-x: hidden"),
                 column(12,
                        br(),
                        align = "left",
                        splitLayout(cellWidths = c("70%", "30%"),
                                    plotOutput("Graphw"),
                                    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.EF == true && input.MonteCarlo == false", tableOutput("EFWeightsTable")),
                                    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.MonteCarlo == true && input.EF == false", tableOutput("MCWeightsTable")),
                                    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.MonteCarlo == true && input.EF == true", tableOutput("EFMCWeightsTable")))),
                 column(12,
                        align = "center",
                        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.EF == true && input.MonteCarlo == false", plotOutput("GraphEF")),
                        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.MonteCarlo == true && input.EF == false", plotOutput("GraphMC")),
                        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.MonteCarlo == true && input.EF == true", plotOutput("GraphEFMC"))
                 )
             )
         )
     )
))


#Server
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    
    
    #CONSTRUCTION
    
    #Store Initial Tickers/Number of Shares/Countries From User Inputs (In Vectors and Data Frame)
    valuesDFw <- reactiveValues() #Initialize Data Frame
    valuesDFw$dfw <- data.frame("Ticker" = numeric(0), "Shares" = numeric(0), "Country" = numeric(0)) 
    valuesVECw <- reactiveValues(tickersw = NULL, SharesVecw = NULL, CountryVecw = NULL) #Initialize Vectors
    
    observeEvent(input$actionw, {
        isolate(valuesDFw$dfw[nrow(valuesDFw$dfw) + 1,] <- c(input$Stockw, input$Sharesw, input$Countryw)) #Store Data frame
        valuesVECw$tickersw <- c(valuesVECw$tickersw,input$Stockw)  #Store Vectors
        valuesVECw$SharesVecw <- c(valuesVECw$SharesVecw,input$Sharesw)
        valuesVECw$CountryVecw <- c(valuesVECw$CountryVecw, input$Countryw)
    })
    
    #Reset Initial Tickers/Number of Shares/Countries From User Inputs (In Vectors and Data Frame)
    observeEvent(input$resetw, {
        valuesVECw$tickersw <- valuesVECw$tickersw[-1:-(length(valuesVECw$tickersw))] #Reset Vectors
        valuesVECw$SharesVecw <- valuesVECw$SharesVecw[-1:-(length(valuesVECw$SharesVecw))]
        valuesVECw$CountryVecw <- valuesVECw$CountryVecw[-1:-(length(valuesVECw$CountryVecw))]
        valuesDFw$dfw <- valuesDFw$dfw[0,] #Reset Data Frame
    })
    
    #Call Function (Defined Bellow)
    OPw <- reactiveValues()
    observeEvent(input$Gow, {
        
        OPw$PC <- Run(valuesVECw$tickersw,valuesVECw$SharesVecw,valuesVECw$CountryVecw)
        
        if(input$EF == TRUE && input$MonteCarlo == FALSE){
            showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer=NULL)) #Creates Loading Pop-up Message
            OPw$LIST1 <- Run2(valuesVECw$tickersw,valuesVECw$SharesVecw,valuesVECw$CountryVecw)
        }
        removeModal() #Removes Loading Pop-up Message
        
        if(input$MonteCarlo == TRUE && input$EF == FALSE){
            showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer=NULL)) #Creates Loading Pop-up Message
            OPw$LIST2 <- Run3(valuesVECw$tickersw,valuesVECw$SharesVecw,valuesVECw$CountryVecw)
        }
        removeModal() #Removes Loading Pop-up Message
        
        if(input$MonteCarlo == TRUE && input$EF == TRUE){
            showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer=NULL)) #Creates Loading Pop-up Message
            OPw$LIST3 <- Run4(valuesVECw$tickersw,valuesVECw$SharesVecw,valuesVECw$CountryVecw)
        }
        removeModal() #Removes Loading Pop-up Message
    })
    
    #Output Variables
    output$tablew <- renderTable({valuesDFw$dfw}) #Initial Holdings Data Frame
    output$Graphw <- renderPlot({ #Pie Chart
        OPw$PC}, height = 400, width = 400)
    
    output$GraphEF <- renderPlot({ #Graph EF
        OPw$LIST1[[1]]
    },height = 550, width = 700)
    
    output$EFWeightsTable <- renderTable({ #Efficient Portfolio Weights Data Frame
        OPw$LIST1[[2]]}, colnames = TRUE
    )
    
    output$GraphMC <- renderPlot({ #Graph MC
        OPw$LIST2[[1]]
    },height = 550, width = 700)
    
    output$MCWeightsTable <- renderTable({ #Efficient Portfolio Weights Data Frame
        OPw$LIST2[[2]]}, colnames = TRUE
    )
    
    output$GraphEFMC <- renderPlot({ #Graph EFMC
        OPw$LIST3[[1]]
    },height = 550, width = 700)
    
    output$EFMCWeightsTable <- renderTable({ #Efficient Portfolio Weights Data Frame
        OPw$LIST3[[2]]}, colnames = TRUE
    )
    
    #Weights Function
    Run <- function(tickersw, SharesVecw, CountryVecw){
        
        USDtoCAD <- getQuote("CAD=X", src = "yahoo")[2] #Convert USD to CAD
        USDtoCAD <- USDtoCAD[[1]] #List to Numeric
        
        #Select Last Prices (From Tickers)
        PortfolioPricesw <- NULL 
        tickersw <- toupper(tickersw) #CAPS
        for (i in tickersw){
            PortfolioPricesw <- cbind(PortfolioPricesw, getQuote(i, src = "yahoo")[,2])          
        }  
        
        #Convert USD Denominated Assets to CAD
        for (i in 1:length(PortfolioPricesw)){
            if(CountryVecw[i] == "United States"){
                PortfolioPricesw[i] <- USDtoCAD*PortfolioPricesw[i]
            }
        }
        
        #Find Weights
        MarketValuew <- SharesVecw*PortfolioPricesw
        Weightsw <- MarketValuew/sum(MarketValuew)*100
        colnames(Weightsw) <- tickersw
        
        #Create Pie Chart 
        tickersw <- tickersw[order(Weightsw)]; Weightsw <- sort(Weightsw)
        Percent <- factor(paste(tickersw, scales::percent(Weightsw/100, accuracy = 0.1)), paste(tickersw, scales::percent(Weightsw/100, accuracy = 0.1)))
        
        Plot <- ggplot() + theme_bw() +
            geom_bar(aes(x = "", y = Weightsw, fill = Percent),
                     stat = "identity", color = "white") + 
            coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
            ggtitle("My Portfolio") +
            theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
                  plot.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold.italic", hjust = 0.5),
                  axis.text = element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                  panel.grid = element_blank(),
                  panel.border = element_blank()) +
            guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) + 
            theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
                  legend.title = element_blank(),
                  legend.key.size = unit(0.8,"cm")) 
        
        #Output
        return(Plot)
    }
    
    #Efficient Frontier Function
    Run2 <- function(tickersw, SharesVecw, CountryVecw){
        
        AdjustedPrices <- NULL
        TargetPrice <- NULL
        CurrentPrice <- NULL
        yret <- NULL
        wret <- NULL
        ReturnsVec <- NULL
        
        get_summary_table <- function(symbol){
            
            url <- paste0("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",symbol)
            df <- url %>%
                read_html() %>%
                html_table(header = FALSE) %>%
                map_df(bind_cols) %>%
                as_tibble()
            
            names(df) <- c("name", "value")
            df["stock"] <- symbol
            
            df
        }
        
        for (i in tickersw){
            AdjustedPrices <- cbind(AdjustedPrices, 
                                    getSymbols.yahoo(i, from = "2019-01-01", to = Sys.Date(),             
                                                     periodicity = "weekly", auto.assign = F)[,6])  
            TargetPrice <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",unlist(get_summary_table(i)[16,2])))
            CurrentPrice <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",unlist(get_summary_table(i)[1,2])))
            yret <- (TargetPrice-CurrentPrice)/CurrentPrice 
            wret <- (1+yret)^(1/52) - 1
            ReturnsVec <- c(ReturnsVec, wret)
        }   
        
        Returnsw <- Return.calculate(AdjustedPrices, method = "discrete")
        Returnsw <- Returnsw[-1,] #Removes NA
        
        #Minimum Variance Portfolio
        sigma <- cov(Returnsw)
        weights_mv <- optimalPortfolio(Sigma = sigma, 
                                       control = list(type = "minvol", constraint = "lo"))
        
        #Efficient Frontier
        ret_min <- sum(ReturnsVec*weights_mv)
        ret_max <- max(ReturnsVec)
        ret_range <- seq(from = ret_min, to = ret_max, length.out = 30)
        
        vol <- rep(NA, 30)
        mu <- rep(NA,30)
        eweights <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(tickersw), ncol = 30)
        
        #Min Weights
        eweights[,1] <- weights_mv
        vol[1] <- sqrt(tcrossprod(crossprod(weights_mv, sigma), weights_mv))
        mu[1] <- ret_min
        
        #Max Weights
        max_ret_idx <- which(ReturnsVec == ret_max)
        w_maxret <- rep(0,length(tickersw))
        w_maxret[max_ret_idx] <- 1
        
        eweights[,30] <- w_maxret
        vol[30] <- apply(Returnsw,2,sd)[max_ret_idx]
        mu[30] <- ReturnsVec[max_ret_idx]
        
        #Rest of Weights
        for (i in 2:29){
            res <- solve.QP(Dmat = sigma, dvec = rep(0,length(tickersw)), Amat = cbind(matrix(rep(1,length(tickersw)), ncol=1), diag(length(tickersw)), matrix(ReturnsVec, ncol=1)), bvec = c(1,rep(0,length(tickersw)), ret_range[i]), meq = 1)
            w <- res$solution
            
            eweights[,i] <- w
            vol[i] <- sqrt(tcrossprod(crossprod(w,sigma),w))
            mu[i] <- sum(ReturnsVec*w)
        }
        
        #My Weights
        USDtoCAD <- getQuote("CAD=X", src = "yahoo")[2] #Convert USD to CAD
        USDtoCAD <- USDtoCAD[[1]] #List to Numeric
        
        #Select Last Prices (From Tickers)
        PortfolioPricesw <- NULL 
        tickersw <- toupper(tickersw) #CAPS
        for (i in tickersw){
            PortfolioPricesw <- cbind(PortfolioPricesw, getQuote(i, src = "yahoo")[,2])          
        }  
        
        #Convert USD Denominated Assets to CAD
        for (i in 1:length(PortfolioPricesw)){
            if(CountryVecw[i] == "United States"){
                PortfolioPricesw[i] <- USDtoCAD*PortfolioPricesw[i]
            }
        }
        
        #Find Weights
        MarketValuew <- SharesVecw*PortfolioPricesw
        Weightsw <- MarketValuew/sum(MarketValuew)
        Weightsw <- as.vector(Weightsw)
        
        MyMu <- sum(ReturnsVec*Weightsw)
        MyVol <- as.numeric(sqrt(tcrossprod(crossprod(Weightsw,sigma),Weightsw)))
        
        eweights <- round(eweights,2)
        eweights <- t(eweights)
        colnames(eweights) <- gsub(".Adjusted", "", colnames(sigma))
        eweights <- abs(eweights[c(1,5,8,12,16,19,23,26,30),])
        
        MYPLOT <- ggplot(as.data.frame(cbind(vol,mu)), aes(vol, mu)) +
            geom_line() +
            geom_point(aes(MyVol,MyMu, colour = "My Portfolio"), 
                       shape = 18, 
                       size = 3) +
            ggtitle("Efficient Frontier") +
            xlab("Volatility (Weekly)") +
            ylab("Expected Returns (Weekly)") +
            theme(plot.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold.italic", hjust = 0.5, margin=margin(0,0,15,0)),
                  axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10, margin=margin(15,0,0,0)),
                  axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10, margin=margin(0,15,0,0)),
                  panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
                  legend.position = c(0.92,0.06),
                  legend.title = element_blank(),
                  legend.text = element_text(size=8),
                  legend.background = element_rect(color = "black"),
                  legend.key=element_blank())
        
        return(list(MYPLOT, eweights))
    }
    
    #Monte Carlo Function
    Run3 <- function(tickersw, SharesVecw, CountryVecw){
        
        AdjustedPrices <- NULL
        TargetPrice <- NULL
        CurrentPrice <- NULL
        yret <- NULL
        wret <- NULL
        ReturnsVec <- NULL
        
        get_summary_table <- function(symbol){
            
            url <- paste0("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",symbol)
            df <- url %>%
                read_html() %>%
                html_table(header = FALSE) %>%
                map_df(bind_cols) %>%
                as_tibble()
            
            names(df) <- c("name", "value")
            df["stock"] <- symbol
            
            df
        }
        
        for (i in tickersw){
            AdjustedPrices <- cbind(AdjustedPrices, 
                                    getSymbols.yahoo(i, from = "2019-01-01", to = Sys.Date(),             
                                                     periodicity = "weekly", auto.assign = F)[,6])  
            TargetPrice <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",unlist(get_summary_table(i)[16,2])))
            CurrentPrice <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",unlist(get_summary_table(i)[1,2])))
            yret <- (TargetPrice-CurrentPrice)/CurrentPrice 
            wret <- (1+yret)^(1/52) - 1
            ReturnsVec <- c(ReturnsVec, wret)
        }   
        
        Returnsw <- Return.calculate(AdjustedPrices, method = "discrete")
        Returnsw <- Returnsw[-1,] #Removes NA
        
        #Minimum Variance Portfolio
        sigma <- cov(Returnsw)
        weights_mv <- optimalPortfolio(Sigma = sigma, 
                                       control = list(type = "minvol", constraint = "lo"))
        
        #Efficient Frontier
        ret_min <- sum(ReturnsVec*weights_mv)
        ret_max <- max(ReturnsVec)
        ret_range <- seq(from = ret_min, to = ret_max, length.out = 30)
        
        vol <- rep(NA, 30)
        mu <- rep(NA,30)
        eweights <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(tickersw), ncol = 30)
        
        #Min Weights
        eweights[,1] <- weights_mv
        vol[1] <- sqrt(tcrossprod(crossprod(weights_mv, sigma), weights_mv))
        mu[1] <- ret_min
        
        #Max Weights
        max_ret_idx <- which(ReturnsVec == ret_max)
        w_maxret <- rep(0,length(tickersw))
        w_maxret[max_ret_idx] <- 1
        
        eweights[,30] <- w_maxret
        vol[30] <- apply(Returnsw,2,sd)[max_ret_idx]
        mu[30] <- ReturnsVec[max_ret_idx]
        
        #Rest of Weights
        for (i in 2:29){
            res <- solve.QP(Dmat = sigma, dvec = rep(0,length(tickersw)), Amat = cbind(matrix(rep(1,length(tickersw)), ncol=1), diag(length(tickersw)), matrix(ReturnsVec, ncol=1)), bvec = c(1,rep(0,length(tickersw)), ret_range[i]), meq = 1)
            w <- res$solution
            
            eweights[,i] <- w
            vol[i] <- sqrt(tcrossprod(crossprod(w,sigma),w))
            mu[i] <- sum(ReturnsVec*w)
        }
        
        #Monte Carlo
        W_Vec <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(tickersw), ncol = 1000)
        VOL <- rep(NA, 1000)
        MU <- rep(NA,1000)
        
        for (i in 1:1000){
            W_Vec[,i] <- runif(length(tickersw)) #Generate 4 random numbers [0,1]
            W_Vec[,i] <- W_Vec[,i]/sum(W_Vec[,i]) #Sum of Weights = 1
            MU[i] <- sum(ReturnsVec*W_Vec[,i])
            VOL[i] <- sqrt(tcrossprod(crossprod(W_Vec[,i],sigma),W_Vec[,i]))
        }
        
        #My Weights
        USDtoCAD <- getQuote("CAD=X", src = "yahoo")[2] #Convert USD to CAD
        USDtoCAD <- USDtoCAD[[1]] #List to Numeric
        
        #Select Last Prices (From Tickers)
        PortfolioPricesw <- NULL 
        tickersw <- toupper(tickersw) #CAPS
        for (i in tickersw){
            PortfolioPricesw <- cbind(PortfolioPricesw, getQuote(i, src = "yahoo")[,2])          
        }  
        
        #Convert USD Denominated Assets to CAD
        for (i in 1:length(PortfolioPricesw)){
            if(CountryVecw[i] == "United States"){
                PortfolioPricesw[i] <- USDtoCAD*PortfolioPricesw[i]
            }
        }
        
        #Find Weights
        MarketValuew <- SharesVecw*PortfolioPricesw
        Weightsw <- MarketValuew/sum(MarketValuew)
        Weightsw <- as.vector(Weightsw)
        
        MyMu <- sum(ReturnsVec*Weightsw)
        MyVol <- as.numeric(sqrt(tcrossprod(crossprod(Weightsw,sigma),Weightsw)))
        
        eweights <- round(eweights,2)
        eweights <- t(eweights)
        colnames(eweights) <- gsub(".Adjusted", "", colnames(sigma))
        eweights <- abs(eweights[c(1,5,8,12,16,19,23,26,30),])
        
        MYPLOT <- ggplot(as.data.frame(cbind(VOL,MU)), aes(VOL, MU)) +
            geom_point(shape = 1) +
            geom_point(aes(MyVol,MyMu, colour = "My Portfolio"), 
                       shape = 18, 
                       size = 3) +
            geom_line(data=data.frame(vol,mu), mapping=aes(vol, mu)) +
            ggtitle("Efficient Frontier") +
            xlab("Volatility (Weekly)") +
            ylab("Expected Returns (Weekly)") +
            theme(plot.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold.italic", hjust = 0.5, margin=margin(0,0,15,0)),
                  axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10, margin=margin(15,0,0,0)),
                  axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10, margin=margin(0,15,0,0)),
                  panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
                  legend.position = c(0.92,0.06),
                  legend.title = element_blank(),
                  legend.text = element_text(size=8),
                  legend.background = element_rect(color = "black"),
                  legend.key=element_blank())
        
        return(list(MYPLOT, eweights))
    }
    
    #Monte Carlo and EF Function
    Run4 <- function(tickersw, SharesVecw, CountryVecw){
        Run3(tickersw, SharesVecw, CountryVecw)
    }
})

shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: To get an answer quickly, you should try to post an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as you did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70810287/r-shiny-checkboxes-and-action-button-combination-issue).  For the second issue, you can use `eventReactive()` as noted in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: I have posted an MRE here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70828547/r-shiny-conditional-panel-output-shifted> if anyone is wondering

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `conditionalPanel` we can use `shinyjs` `show` and `hide` inside `observeEvent`. This way the changes in the ui will happen **after** the button is pressed.

Inside the ui we call `useShinyjs()` and then for the server part we add:

```
    observeEvent(input$Gow, {
        #print(input$EF)
        list(c('EF', 'MonteCarlo'), c('EFWeightsTable', 'MCWeightsTable'), c('GraphEF', 'GraphMC')) %>% 
            pmap(~ {
                if(as.logical(input[[..1]])) {
                    shinyjs::show(..2)
                    shinyjs::show(..3)
                } else {
                    shinyjs::hide(..2)
                    shinyjs::hide(..3)
                }
            })
    })
```

This will loop through the checkboxes to see, if there is a TRUE value then show, otherwise hide the outputs.

full app code:

```
library(shiny)
library(quantmod)                            
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(zoo)
library(xts)
library(plyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(RiskPortfolios)
library(quadprog)
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Analysis",
                         useShinyjs(), 
                         tabPanel(
                             "Performance",
                             
                             titlePanel("Performance"),
                             br(),
                             
                             sidebarLayout(
                                 sidebarPanel(
                                 ),
                                 mainPanel(
                                 )
                             )),
                         
                         tabPanel(
                             
                             "Construction",
                             
                             titlePanel("Construction"),
                             br(),
                             
                             sidebarLayout(
                                 sidebarPanel(
                                     textInput("Stockw","Ticker (Yahoo)"),
                                     numericInput("Sharesw","Number of Shares",0, min = 0, step = 1),
                                     selectInput("Countryw","Country",choices = c("Canada","United States")),
                                     
                                     column(12,
                                            splitLayout(cellWidths = c("70%", "30%"),
                                                        actionButton("actionw", "Add",icon("dollar-sign"),  
                                                                     style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"),
                                                        actionButton("resetw", "Reset",icon("trash"),  
                                                                     style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4"))),
                                     
                                     br(),
                                     br(),
                                     checkboxInput("EF", "Efficient Frontier"),
                                     checkboxInput("MonteCarlo", "Monte Carlo Simulation"),
                                     
                                     fluidRow(
                                         align = "center",
                                         p("____________________________________"),
                                         p("Ready to launch?", style = "font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold"),
                                         actionButton("Gow", "Go!", style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4; margin: auto")),
                                     
                                 ),
                                 
                                 mainPanel(
                                     column(12,
                                            tableOutput("tablew"), 
                                            style = "height:185px; overflow-y: scroll; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; border-radius: 8px; background-color: #f7f7f7;text-align: left; overflow-x: hidden"),
                                     column(12,
                                            br(),
                                            align = "left",
                                            splitLayout(cellWidths = c("70%", "30%"),
                                                        plotOutput("Graphw"),
                                                        hidden(tableOutput("EFWeightsTable")),
                                                        hidden(tableOutput("MCWeightsTable")),
                                                        )),
                                     column(12,
                                            align = "center",
                                            hidden(plotOutput("GraphEF")),
                                            hidden(plotOutput("GraphMC")),
                                            #plotOutput("GraphEFMC")
                                     )
                                 )
                             )
                         )
))


#Server
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    
    observeEvent(input$Gow, {
        #print(input$EF)
        list(c('EF', 'MonteCarlo'), c('EFWeightsTable', 'MCWeightsTable'), c('GraphEF', 'GraphMC')) %>% 
            pmap(~ {
                if(as.logical(input[[..1]])) {
                    shinyjs::show(..2)
                    shinyjs::show(..3)
                } else {
                    shinyjs::hide(..2)
                    shinyjs::hide(..3)
                }
            })
    })
    
    #CONSTRUCTION
    
    #Store Initial Tickers/Number of Shares/Countries From User Inputs (In Vectors and Data Frame)
    valuesDFw <- reactiveValues() #Initialize Data Frame
    valuesDFw$dfw <- data.frame("Ticker" = numeric(0), "Shares" = numeric(0), "Country" = numeric(0)) 
    valuesVECw <- reactiveValues(tickersw = NULL, SharesVecw = NULL, CountryVecw = NULL) #Initialize Vectors
    
    observeEvent(input$actionw, {
        isolate(valuesDFw$dfw[nrow(valuesDFw$dfw) + 1,] <- c(input$Stockw, input$Sharesw, input$Countryw)) #Store Data frame
        valuesVECw$tickersw <- c(valuesVECw$tickersw,input$Stockw)  #Store Vectors
        valuesVECw$SharesVecw <- c(valuesVECw$SharesVecw,input$Sharesw)
        valuesVECw$CountryVecw <- c(valuesVECw$CountryVecw, input$Countryw)
    })
    
    #Reset Initial Tickers/Number of Shares/Countries From User Inputs (In Vectors and Data Frame)
    observeEvent(input$resetw, {
        valuesVECw$tickersw <- valuesVECw$tickersw[-1:-(length(valuesVECw$tickersw))] #Reset Vectors
        valuesVECw$SharesVecw <- valuesVECw$SharesVecw[-1:-(length(valuesVECw$SharesVecw))]
        valuesVECw$CountryVecw <- valuesVECw$CountryVecw[-1:-(length(valuesVECw$CountryVecw))]
        valuesDFw$dfw <- valuesDFw$dfw[0,] #Reset Data Frame
    })
    
    #Call Function (Defined Bellow)
    OPw <- reactiveValues()
    observeEvent(input$Gow, {
        
        OPw$PC <- Run(valuesVECw$tickersw,valuesVECw$SharesVecw,valuesVECw$CountryVecw)
        
        if(input$EF == TRUE && input$MonteCarlo == FALSE){
            showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer=NULL)) #Creates Loading Pop-up Message
            OPw$LIST1 <- Run2(valuesVECw$tickersw,valuesVECw$SharesVecw,valuesVECw$CountryVecw)
        }
        removeModal() #Removes Loading Pop-up Message
        
        if(input$MonteCarlo == TRUE && input$EF == FALSE){
            showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer=NULL)) #Creates Loading Pop-up Message
            OPw$LIST2 <- Run3(valuesVECw$tickersw,valuesVECw$SharesVecw,valuesVECw$CountryVecw)
        }
        removeModal() #Removes Loading Pop-up Message
        
        if(input$MonteCarlo == TRUE && input$EF == TRUE){
            showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer=NULL)) #Creates Loading Pop-up Message
            OPw$LIST3 <- Run4(valuesVECw$tickersw,valuesVECw$SharesVecw,valuesVECw$CountryVecw)
        }
        removeModal() #Removes Loading Pop-up Message
    })
    
    #Output Variables
    output$tablew <- renderTable({valuesDFw$dfw}) #Initial Holdings Data Frame
    output$Graphw <- renderPlot({ #Pie Chart
        OPw$PC}, height = 400, width = 400)
    
    output$GraphEF <- renderPlot({ #Graph EF
        OPw$LIST1[[1]]
    },height = 550, width = 700)
    
    output$EFWeightsTable <- renderTable({ #Efficient Portfolio Weights Data Frame
        OPw$LIST1[[2]]}, colnames = TRUE
    )
    
    output$GraphMC <- renderPlot({ #Graph MC
        OPw$LIST2[[1]]
    },height = 550, width = 700)
    
    output$MCWeightsTable <- renderTable({ #Efficient Portfolio Weights Data Frame
        OPw$LIST2[[2]]}, colnames = TRUE
    )
    
    output$GraphEFMC <- renderPlot({ #Graph EFMC
        OPw$LIST3[[1]]
    },height = 550, width = 700)
    
    output$EFMCWeightsTable <- renderTable({ #Efficient Portfolio Weights Data Frame
        OPw$LIST3[[2]]}, colnames = TRUE
    )
    
    #Weights Function
    Run <- function(tickersw, SharesVecw, CountryVecw){
        
        USDtoCAD <- getQuote("CAD=X", src = "yahoo")[2] #Convert USD to CAD
        USDtoCAD <- USDtoCAD[[1]] #List to Numeric
        
        #Select Last Prices (From Tickers)
        PortfolioPricesw <- NULL 
        tickersw <- toupper(tickersw) #CAPS
        for (i in tickersw){
            PortfolioPricesw <- cbind(PortfolioPricesw, getQuote(i, src = "yahoo")[,2])          
        }  
        
        #Convert USD Denominated Assets to CAD
        for (i in 1:length(PortfolioPricesw)){
            if(CountryVecw[i] == "United States"){
                PortfolioPricesw[i] <- USDtoCAD*PortfolioPricesw[i]
            }
        }
        
        #Find Weights
        MarketValuew <- SharesVecw*PortfolioPricesw
        Weightsw <- MarketValuew/sum(MarketValuew)*100
        colnames(Weightsw) <- tickersw
        
        #Create Pie Chart 
        tickersw <- tickersw[order(Weightsw)]; Weightsw <- sort(Weightsw)
        Percent <- factor(paste(tickersw, scales::percent(Weightsw/100, accuracy = 0.1)), paste(tickersw, scales::percent(Weightsw/100, accuracy = 0.1)))
        
        Plot <- ggplot() + theme_bw() +
            geom_bar(aes(x = "", y = Weightsw, fill = Percent),
                     stat = "identity", color = "white") + 
            coord_polar("y", start = 0) +
            ggtitle("My Portfolio") +
            theme(axis.title = element_blank(),
                  plot.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold.italic", hjust = 0.5),
                  axis.text = element_blank(),
                  axis.ticks = element_blank(),
                  panel.grid = element_blank(),
                  panel.border = element_blank()) +
            guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) + 
            theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 12),
                  legend.title = element_blank(),
                  legend.key.size = unit(0.8,"cm")) 
        
        #Output
        return(Plot)
    }
    
    #Efficient Frontier Function
    Run2 <- function(tickersw, SharesVecw, CountryVecw){
        
        AdjustedPrices <- NULL
        TargetPrice <- NULL
        CurrentPrice <- NULL
        yret <- NULL
        wret <- NULL
        ReturnsVec <- NULL
        
        get_summary_table <- function(symbol){
            
            url <- paste0("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",symbol)
            df <- url %>%
                read_html() %>%
                html_table(header = FALSE) %>%
                map_df(bind_cols) %>%
                as_tibble()
            
            names(df) <- c("name", "value")
            df["stock"] <- symbol
            
            df
        }
        
        for (i in tickersw){
            AdjustedPrices <- cbind(AdjustedPrices, 
                                    getSymbols.yahoo(i, from = "2019-01-01", to = Sys.Date(),             
                                                     periodicity = "weekly", auto.assign = F)[,6])  
            TargetPrice <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",unlist(get_summary_table(i)[16,2])))
            CurrentPrice <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",unlist(get_summary_table(i)[1,2])))
            yret <- (TargetPrice-CurrentPrice)/CurrentPrice 
            wret <- (1+yret)^(1/52) - 1
            ReturnsVec <- c(ReturnsVec, wret)
        }   
        
        Returnsw <- Return.calculate(AdjustedPrices, method = "discrete")
        Returnsw <- Returnsw[-1,] #Removes NA
        
        #Minimum Variance Portfolio
        sigma <- cov(Returnsw)
        weights_mv <- optimalPortfolio(Sigma = sigma, 
                                       control = list(type = "minvol", constraint = "lo"))
        
        #Efficient Frontier
        ret_min <- sum(ReturnsVec*weights_mv)
        ret_max <- max(ReturnsVec)
        ret_range <- seq(from = ret_min, to = ret_max, length.out = 30)
        
        vol <- rep(NA, 30)
        mu <- rep(NA,30)
        eweights <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(tickersw), ncol = 30)
        
        #Min Weights
        eweights[,1] <- weights_mv
        vol[1] <- sqrt(tcrossprod(crossprod(weights_mv, sigma), weights_mv))
        mu[1] <- ret_min
        
        #Max Weights
        max_ret_idx <- which(ReturnsVec == ret_max)
        w_maxret <- rep(0,length(tickersw))
        w_maxret[max_ret_idx] <- 1
        
        eweights[,30] <- w_maxret
        vol[30] <- apply(Returnsw,2,sd)[max_ret_idx]
        mu[30] <- ReturnsVec[max_ret_idx]
        
        #Rest of Weights
        for (i in 2:29){
            res <- solve.QP(Dmat = sigma, dvec = rep(0,length(tickersw)), Amat = cbind(matrix(rep(1,length(tickersw)), ncol=1), diag(length(tickersw)), matrix(ReturnsVec, ncol=1)), bvec = c(1,rep(0,length(tickersw)), ret_range[i]), meq = 1)
            w <- res$solution
            
            eweights[,i] <- w
            vol[i] <- sqrt(tcrossprod(crossprod(w,sigma),w))
            mu[i] <- sum(ReturnsVec*w)
        }
        
        #My Weights
        USDtoCAD <- getQuote("CAD=X", src = "yahoo")[2] #Convert USD to CAD
        USDtoCAD <- USDtoCAD[[1]] #List to Numeric
        
        #Select Last Prices (From Tickers)
        PortfolioPricesw <- NULL 
        tickersw <- toupper(tickersw) #CAPS
        for (i in tickersw){
            PortfolioPricesw <- cbind(PortfolioPricesw, getQuote(i, src = "yahoo")[,2])          
        }  
        
        #Convert USD Denominated Assets to CAD
        for (i in 1:length(PortfolioPricesw)){
            if(CountryVecw[i] == "United States"){
                PortfolioPricesw[i] <- USDtoCAD*PortfolioPricesw[i]
            }
        }
        
        #Find Weights
        MarketValuew <- SharesVecw*PortfolioPricesw
        Weightsw <- MarketValuew/sum(MarketValuew)
        Weightsw <- as.vector(Weightsw)
        
        MyMu <- sum(ReturnsVec*Weightsw)
        MyVol <- as.numeric(sqrt(tcrossprod(crossprod(Weightsw,sigma),Weightsw)))
        
        eweights <- round(eweights,2)
        eweights <- t(eweights)
        colnames(eweights) <- gsub(".Adjusted", "", colnames(sigma))
        eweights <- abs(eweights[c(1,5,8,12,16,19,23,26,30),])
        
        MYPLOT <- ggplot(as.data.frame(cbind(vol,mu)), aes(vol, mu)) +
            geom_line() +
            geom_point(aes(MyVol,MyMu, colour = "My Portfolio"), 
                       shape = 18, 
                       size = 3) +
            ggtitle("Efficient Frontier") +
            xlab("Volatility (Weekly)") +
            ylab("Expected Returns (Weekly)") +
            theme(plot.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold.italic", hjust = 0.5, margin=margin(0,0,15,0)),
                  axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10, margin=margin(15,0,0,0)),
                  axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10, margin=margin(0,15,0,0)),
                  panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
                  legend.position = c(0.92,0.06),
                  legend.title = element_blank(),
                  legend.text = element_text(size=8),
                  legend.background = element_rect(color = "black"),
                  legend.key=element_blank())
        
        return(list(MYPLOT, eweights))
    }
    
    #Monte Carlo Function
    Run3 <- function(tickersw, SharesVecw, CountryVecw){
        
        AdjustedPrices <- NULL
        TargetPrice <- NULL
        CurrentPrice <- NULL
        yret <- NULL
        wret <- NULL
        ReturnsVec <- NULL
        
        get_summary_table <- function(symbol){
            
            url <- paste0("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/",symbol)
            df <- url %>%
                read_html() %>%
                html_table(header = FALSE) %>%
                map_df(bind_cols) %>%
                as_tibble()
            
            names(df) <- c("name", "value")
            df["stock"] <- symbol
            
            df
        }
        
        for (i in tickersw){
            AdjustedPrices <- cbind(AdjustedPrices, 
                                    getSymbols.yahoo(i, from = "2019-01-01", to = Sys.Date(),             
                                                     periodicity = "weekly", auto.assign = F)[,6])  
            TargetPrice <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",unlist(get_summary_table(i)[16,2])))
            CurrentPrice <- as.numeric(gsub(",","",unlist(get_summary_table(i)[1,2])))
            yret <- (TargetPrice-CurrentPrice)/CurrentPrice 
            wret <- (1+yret)^(1/52) - 1
            ReturnsVec <- c(ReturnsVec, wret)
        }   
        
        Returnsw <- Return.calculate(AdjustedPrices, method = "discrete")
        Returnsw <- Returnsw[-1,] #Removes NA
        
        #Minimum Variance Portfolio
        sigma <- cov(Returnsw)
        weights_mv <- optimalPortfolio(Sigma = sigma, 
                                       control = list(type = "minvol", constraint = "lo"))
        
        #Efficient Frontier
        ret_min <- sum(ReturnsVec*weights_mv)
        ret_max <- max(ReturnsVec)
        ret_range <- seq(from = ret_min, to = ret_max, length.out = 30)
        
        vol <- rep(NA, 30)
        mu <- rep(NA,30)
        eweights <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(tickersw), ncol = 30)
        
        #Min Weights
        eweights[,1] <- weights_mv
        vol[1] <- sqrt(tcrossprod(crossprod(weights_mv, sigma), weights_mv))
        mu[1] <- ret_min
        
        #Max Weights
        max_ret_idx <- which(ReturnsVec == ret_max)
        w_maxret <- rep(0,length(tickersw))
        w_maxret[max_ret_idx] <- 1
        
        eweights[,30] <- w_maxret
        vol[30] <- apply(Returnsw,2,sd)[max_ret_idx]
        mu[30] <- ReturnsVec[max_ret_idx]
        
        #Rest of Weights
        for (i in 2:29){
            res <- solve.QP(Dmat = sigma, dvec = rep(0,length(tickersw)), Amat = cbind(matrix(rep(1,length(tickersw)), ncol=1), diag(length(tickersw)), matrix(ReturnsVec, ncol=1)), bvec = c(1,rep(0,length(tickersw)), ret_range[i]), meq = 1)
            w <- res$solution
            
            eweights[,i] <- w
            vol[i] <- sqrt(tcrossprod(crossprod(w,sigma),w))
            mu[i] <- sum(ReturnsVec*w)
        }
        
        #Monte Carlo
        W_Vec <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(tickersw), ncol = 1000)
        VOL <- rep(NA, 1000)
        MU <- rep(NA,1000)
        
        for (i in 1:1000){
            W_Vec[,i] <- runif(length(tickersw)) #Generate 4 random numbers [0,1]
            W_Vec[,i] <- W_Vec[,i]/sum(W_Vec[,i]) #Sum of Weights = 1
            MU[i] <- sum(ReturnsVec*W_Vec[,i])
            VOL[i] <- sqrt(tcrossprod(crossprod(W_Vec[,i],sigma),W_Vec[,i]))
        }
        
        #My Weights
        USDtoCAD <- getQuote("CAD=X", src = "yahoo")[2] #Convert USD to CAD
        USDtoCAD <- USDtoCAD[[1]] #List to Numeric
        
        #Select Last Prices (From Tickers)
        PortfolioPricesw <- NULL 
        tickersw <- toupper(tickersw) #CAPS
        for (i in tickersw){
            PortfolioPricesw <- cbind(PortfolioPricesw, getQuote(i, src = "yahoo")[,2])          
        }  
        
        #Convert USD Denominated Assets to CAD
        for (i in 1:length(PortfolioPricesw)){
            if(CountryVecw[i] == "United States"){
                PortfolioPricesw[i] <- USDtoCAD*PortfolioPricesw[i]
            }
        }
        
        #Find Weights
        MarketValuew <- SharesVecw*PortfolioPricesw
        Weightsw <- MarketValuew/sum(MarketValuew)
        Weightsw <- as.vector(Weightsw)
        
        MyMu <- sum(ReturnsVec*Weightsw)
        MyVol <- as.numeric(sqrt(tcrossprod(crossprod(Weightsw,sigma),Weightsw)))
        
        eweights <- round(eweights,2)
        eweights <- t(eweights)
        colnames(eweights) <- gsub(".Adjusted", "", colnames(sigma))
        eweights <- abs(eweights[c(1,5,8,12,16,19,23,26,30),])
        
        MYPLOT <- ggplot(as.data.frame(cbind(VOL,MU)), aes(VOL, MU)) +
            geom_point(shape = 1) +
            geom_point(aes(MyVol,MyMu, colour = "My Portfolio"), 
                       shape = 18, 
                       size = 3) +
            geom_line(data=data.frame(vol,mu), mapping=aes(vol, mu)) +
            ggtitle("Efficient Frontier") +
            xlab("Volatility (Weekly)") +
            ylab("Expected Returns (Weekly)") +
            theme(plot.title = element_text(size=14, face="bold.italic", hjust = 0.5, margin=margin(0,0,15,0)),
                  axis.title.x = element_text(size = 10, margin=margin(15,0,0,0)),
                  axis.title.y = element_text(size = 10, margin=margin(0,15,0,0)),
                  panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=1),
                  legend.position = c(0.92,0.06),
                  legend.title = element_blank(),
                  legend.text = element_text(size=8),
                  legend.background = element_rect(color = "black"),
                  legend.key=element_blank())
        
        return(list(MYPLOT, eweights))
    }
    
    #Monte Carlo and EF Function
    Run4 <- function(tickersw, SharesVecw, CountryVecw){
        Run3(tickersw, SharesVecw, CountryVecw)
    }
})

shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```