# R SHINY - Conditional panel output shifted?

Tags: r, shiny

This post is related to [R shiny - Checkbox and conditional panels issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70827334/r-shiny-checkbox-and-conditional-panels-issues). I have here managed to create an MRE of the problem.

To sum it up again, when clicking on the second checkbox OR the first and second checkbox at the same time, the data frame output is shifted... I would like it to be displayed at the same position as it is when you click on the first checkbox.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
     
     titlePanel("Construction"),
         
         sidebarLayout(
             sidebarPanel(
                 checkboxInput("EF", "Efficient Frontier"),
                 checkboxInput("MonteCarlo", "Monte Carlo Simulation"),
                 
                 fluidRow(
                     align = "center",
                     actionButton("Gow", "Go!")),
                 
             ),
             
             mainPanel(
                 column(12,
                        br(),
                        align = "left",
                        splitLayout(cellWidths = c("70%", "30%"),
                                    plotOutput("Graphw"),
                                    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.EF == true && input.MonteCarlo == false", tableOutput("EFWeightsTable")),
                                    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.MonteCarlo == true && input.EF == false", tableOutput("MCWeightsTable")),
                                    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.MonteCarlo == true && input.EF == true", tableOutput("EFMCWeightsTable")))),
                 column(12,
                        align = "center",
                        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.EF == true && input.MonteCarlo == false", plotOutput("GraphEF")),
                        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.MonteCarlo == true && input.EF == false", plotOutput("GraphMC")),
                        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.MonteCarlo == true && input.EF == true", plotOutput("GraphEFMC"))
                 )
             )
         )
     )
)


#Server
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

    OPw <- reactiveValues()
    observeEvent(input$Gow, {
        
        OPw$PC <- Run(1,2,3)
        
        if(input$EF == TRUE && input$MonteCarlo == FALSE){
            showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer=NULL)) 
            OPw$LIST1 <- Run2(1,2,3)
        }
        removeModal() 
        
        if(input$MonteCarlo == TRUE && input$EF == FALSE){
            showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer=NULL)) 
            OPw$LIST2 <- Run3(1,2,3)
        }
        removeModal() 
        
        if(input$MonteCarlo == TRUE && input$EF == TRUE){
            showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait", footer=NULL)) 
            OPw$LIST3 <- Run4(1,2,3)
        }
        removeModal() 
    })
    
    #Output Variables
    output$Graphw <- renderPlot({ 
        OPw$PC}, height = 400, width = 400)
    
    output$GraphEF <- renderPlot({ 
        OPw$LIST1[[1]]
    },height = 550, width = 700)
    
    output$EFWeightsTable <- renderTable({ 
        OPw$LIST1[[2]]}, colnames = TRUE
    )
    
    output$GraphMC <- renderPlot({ 
        OPw$LIST2[[1]]
    },height = 550, width = 700)
    
    output$MCWeightsTable <- renderTable({ 
        OPw$LIST2[[2]]}, colnames = TRUE
    )
    
    output$GraphEFMC <- renderPlot({ 
        OPw$LIST3[[1]]
    },height = 550, width = 700)
    
    output$EFMCWeightsTable <- renderTable({ 
        OPw$LIST3[[2]]}, colnames = TRUE
    )
    
    #FUNCTIONS
    Run <- function(a, b, c){
        
        Plot <- ggplot(as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4))), aes(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,4))) +
            geom_line() 
        
        return(Plot)
    }
    
    Run2 <- function(a,b,c){
        
        eweights <- data.frame(cbind(seq(1,9),seq(1,9),seq(1,9)))
        
        MYPLOT <- ggplot(as.data.frame(cbind(c(10,7,4),c(5,6,7))), aes(c(10,7,4), c(5,6,7))) +
            geom_line() 
            
        return(list(MYPLOT, eweights))
    }
    
    Run3 <- function(a,b,c){
        
        eweights <- data.frame(cbind(seq(2,10),seq(2,10),seq(2,10)))
        
        MYPLOT <- ggplot(as.data.frame(cbind(c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9))), aes(c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9))) +
            geom_line() 
        
        return(list(MYPLOT, eweights))
    }
    
    Run4 <- function(a,b,c){
        Run3(a,b,c)
    }
})

shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of `renderUI()` should help you.  Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  
  titlePanel("Construction"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("EF", "Efficient Frontier"),
      checkboxInput("MonteCarlo", "Monte Carlo Simulation"),
      
      fluidRow(
        align = "center",
        actionButton("Gow", "Go!")),
      
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      column(12,
             br(),
             align = "left",
             splitLayout(cellWidths = c("70%", "30%"),
                         plotOutput("Graphw"), uiOutput("mytable")
                         )),
      column(12,
             align = "center",
             conditionalPanel(condition = "input.EF == true && input.MonteCarlo == false", plotOutput("GraphEF")),
             conditionalPanel(condition = "input.MonteCarlo == true && input.EF == false", plotOutput("GraphMC")),
             conditionalPanel(condition = "input.MonteCarlo == true && input.EF == true", plotOutput("GraphEFMC"))
      )
    )
  )
)
)

#Server
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  OPw <- reactiveValues()
  observeEvent(input$Gow, {
    
    OPw$PC <- Run(1,2,3)
    
    if(input$EF == TRUE && input$MonteCarlo == FALSE){
      showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait 1", footer=NULL)) 
      OPw$LIST1 <- Run2(1,2,3)
    }
    removeModal() 
    
    if(input$MonteCarlo == TRUE && input$EF == FALSE){
      showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait 2", footer=NULL)) 
      OPw$LIST2 <- Run3(1,2,3)
    }
    removeModal() 
    
    if(input$MonteCarlo == TRUE && input$EF == TRUE){
      showModal(modalDialog("Loading... Please Wait 3", footer=NULL)) 
      OPw$LIST3 <- Run4(1,2,3)
    }
    removeModal() 
  })
  
  #Output Variables
  output$Graphw <- renderPlot({ 
    OPw$PC}, height = 400, width = 400)
  
  output$GraphEF <- renderPlot({ 
    OPw$LIST1[[1]]
  },height = 550, width = 700)
  
  output$EFWeightsTable <- renderTable({ 
    OPw$LIST1[[2]]}, colnames = TRUE
  )
  
  output$GraphMC <- renderPlot({ 
    OPw$LIST2[[1]]
  },height = 550, width = 700)
  
  output$MCWeightsTable <- renderTable({ 
    OPw$LIST2[[2]]}, colnames = TRUE
  )
  
  output$GraphEFMC <- renderPlot({ 
    OPw$LIST3[[1]]
  },height = 550, width = 700)
  
  output$EFMCWeightsTable <- renderTable({ 
    OPw$LIST3[[2]]}, colnames = TRUE
  )
  
  output$mytable <- renderUI({
    if (input$EF & !input$MonteCarlo) {tableOutput("EFWeightsTable")
    } else if (!input$EF & input$MonteCarlo){tableOutput("MCWeightsTable")
    } else if (input$EF & input$MonteCarlo){tableOutput("EFMCWeightsTable")
    } else return(NULL)
  })
  
  #FUNCTIONS
  Run <- function(a, b, c){
    
    Plot <- ggplot(as.data.frame(cbind(c(1,2,3),c(2,3,4))), aes(c(1,2,3), c(2,3,4))) +
      geom_line() 
    
    return(Plot)
  }
  
  Run2 <- function(a,b,c){
    
    eweights <- data.frame(cbind(seq(1,9),seq(1,9),seq(1,9)))
    
    MYPLOT <- ggplot(as.data.frame(cbind(c(10,7,4),c(5,6,7))), aes(c(10,7,4), c(5,6,7))) +
      geom_line() 
    
    return(list(MYPLOT, eweights))
  }
  
  Run3 <- function(a,b,c){
    
    eweights <- data.frame(cbind(seq(2,10),seq(2,10),seq(2,10)))
    
    MYPLOT <- ggplot(as.data.frame(cbind(c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9))), aes(c(4,5,6),c(7,8,9))) +
      geom_line() 
    
    return(list(MYPLOT, eweights))
  }
  
  Run4 <- function(a,b,c){
    Run3(a,b,c)
  }
})

shinyApp (ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: You re a beast :)

Comment: @DDigits I'd avoid `renderUI` as it takes a unnecessary detour to the server (costs time) which is not the case for @yake84's answer.

Comment: @ismirsehregal, that is true in this example.  However, if the decision to display or not is based on another action button in addition to the checkbox, it may be better to process it on the server side as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70810287/r-shiny-checkboxes-and-action-button-combination-issue)

Comment: Hey @YBS, also the `actionButton` situation can be solved via `conditionalPanel`. I left an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70810287/r-shiny-checkboxes-and-action-button-combination-issue/70834087#70834087). Of course, this only matters once the app is growing and `renderUI` still is a reasonable approach to this problem.

Comment: @ismirsehregal, agreed.  My point was if the complexity keeps growing...

Comment: Another UI based (and therefore fast) approach is using hidden `tabsetPanel`'s along with `updateTabsetPanel`. This might be a little more readable than `conditionalPanel`'s. Please see [this example](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html#dynamic-visibility).

Comment: `tabsetPanel` approach with `updateTabsetPanel` is a great way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I see you already accepted an answer but I had already put in the work. I used a `list()` object for the conditions and that seemed to work. You can cut down most of the server code by making simple objects as placeholders.

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("EF", "Efficient Frontier"),
      checkboxInput("MonteCarlo", "Monte Carlo Simulation")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      column(12, # if these are supposed to stack, I'd use `fluidRow()`
        align = "left",
        splitLayout(
          cellWidths = c("70%", "30%"),
          plotOutput("Graphw"),
          list(  # I made this a list object
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.EF == true && input.MonteCarlo == false", tableOutput("EFWeightsTable")),
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.MonteCarlo == true && input.EF == false", tableOutput("MCWeightsTable")),
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.MonteCarlo == true && input.EF == true", tableOutput("EFMCWeightsTable"))
          )
        )
      ),
      column(12,
        align = "center",
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.EF == true && input.MonteCarlo == false", plotOutput("GraphEF")),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.MonteCarlo == true && input.EF == false", plotOutput("GraphMC")),
        conditionalPanel(condition = "input.MonteCarlo == true && input.EF == true", plotOutput("GraphEFMC"))
      )
    )
  )
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {  
  # dummy tables
  df <- mtcars[1:3, 1:3]
  output$tablew <- renderTable(df)
  output$EFWeightsTable <- renderTable(df)
  output$MCWeightsTable <- renderTable(df)
  output$EFMCWeightsTable <- renderTable(df)
  # dummy plots
  output$GraphEF <- renderPlot(plot(1, 1, main = "Efficient Frontier"))
  output$GraphMC <- renderPlot(plot(1, 1, main = "Monte Carlo"))
  output$GraphEFMC <- renderPlot(plot(1, 1, main = "Both"))
  output$Graphw <- renderPlot(plot(1, 1, main = "Graph W"))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I prefer this UI based solution. However, I'd use `tagList()` instead of `list()` because `conditionalPanel` results in a `div-tag` - but that's just eye-candy.